# Using a PC PSU instead of a dedicated professional "brick"?

Tags: power-supply

Usually when choosing a PSU for a scientific instrument going into production I will go to one of the major distributors and buy something like [this](http://uk.farnell.com/xp-power/sdh400pd1224/power-supply-ac-dc-2-o-p-400w/dp/2451804), which is rather expensive but well specified.
[image]
However, I note that PC PSUs with the same ballpark ratings are a fraction of that price. What are the pros and cons of using the PC PSU?

Comment: From the product page you linked to, "The SDH400 series provide up to 400W with **only convection cooling** in a **low profile**" gives two advantages already.

Comment: PC power supplies are a tad more complicated than a dedicated rail supply. That adds unnecessary complexity and can reduce reliability.

Comment: @AndrewMorton True, but I was only using that as a generic example. I could have picked any other expensive professional PSU at random

Comment: There could be a few disadvantages to use a regular PC PSU, but I'm pretty sure the price difference is only due to the volumes sold and economies of scale. If "XP Power" was selling as many units of the PSU you shown as Corsair sells a typical PC PSU, it wouldn't be more expensive.